# Ubuntu 20.04 - How to remove software RAID 1

Tags: ubuntu, raid1

How can I safely turn of software RAID 1 and make sure systems uses only one of the drives, like let's say `sda`.

Here is some info:

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  1.3M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/md127p1     40G   35G  2.6G  94% /
tmpfs           7.9G  4.0K  7.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md0p1       49G  8.5G   38G  19% /var
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000
```

Output of `cat /etc/fstab`:

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/disk/by-uuid/9e905102-9a35-4d74-a181-513e2c8bb342 none swap sw 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/9ed2eb9e-70d2-4fa1-b18b-cccb809327f2 none swap sw 0 0
# / was on /dev/md127p1 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-id/md-uuid-8cebc92a:c7b2af7b:ddd9d611:631a5229-part1 / ext4 defaults 0 0
# /var was on /dev/md0p1 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-id/md-uuid-81bb4e36:54a0a6db:b1f2250e:bdf5f3d9-part1 /var ext4 defaults 0 0
/swap.img   none    swap    sw  0   0
```

Here is more info:

```
sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Wed Dec  9 10:23:16 2020
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 52391936 (49.96 GiB 53.65 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 52391936 (49.96 GiB 53.65 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Wed Nov 22 19:40:25 2023
             State : active 
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : resync

              Name : ubuntu-server:0
              UUID : 81bb4e36:54a0a6db:b1f2250e:bdf5f3d9
            Events : 9618

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       2       8       19        0      active sync   /dev/sdb3
       1       8        2        1      active sync   /dev/sda2
```

As far as I understand I have software RAID1 between /dev/sdb3 and /dev/sda2.

My question is how can I turn that off completely and use only /dev/sda2 for booting and running the system?